# enterprise architect: import binary module .NET

Tags: .net, enterprise-architect

I tried several times to import 'System.Web.dll' from the .NET Framework by binary module import.

```
Output "Reverse Engineering Process":
"Reverse Engineering Classes:
--importing C:\...\System.Web.dll
Resolving relationships
Import Complete!"
parameters: with diagramm, overwrite existing classes, ...
```

But EA doesn't create any packages or diagramms.Why?
Thanks.

Comment: I am sure you know this already but just incase someone else doesn't, a good place to start looking is here [Sparx Import Binary](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/software_engineering/importbinary.html)

Comment: Any luck?  What version are you using?  What version of .net are you importing?  I've tried with EA 12.0.1214 with .NET 4 - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Web.dll.  But it doesn't import fully for me.  Particularly the View class.